# VBA Powerpoint. How to get file's current directory path to a string in VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

VBA Powerpoint. How can i set environment current directory?

I also tried this code:

```
Sub test()
Dim sPath As String
sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
MsgBox sPath
End Sub
```

But is says: `Object required`

Please help me to make it work ...

Comment: ActivePresentation.Path

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tim has provided the answer. The file path of the active presentation is stored in the property, `ActivePresentation.Path`. If the presentation file has not been saved yet this property will contain an empty string. To test this out you could use something like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = ActivePresentation.Path
    If Len(sPath) > 0 Then
        MsgBox ActivePresentation.Name & vbNewLine & "saved under" & vbNewLine & sPath
    Else
        MsgBox "File not saved"
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this is a read-only property.  You can't set this variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.path